# The constructor CompanyDetail() is undefined (java)

Tags: java, constructor

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CompanyDetail {

    int Id;
    String name;
    String department;
    static String companyname="Maruti Suzuki";

    CompanyDetail(int ID,String Name,String Dept) {
        Id=ID;
        name=Name;
        department=Dept;
    }

    public void getdata() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            System.out.println("Employee Id :");
            Id = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.println("Employee name :");
            name= br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Employee Department :");
            department=br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Company is :"+companyname);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
    public void printdata() {
        System.out.println("Employee Id is :"+Id);
        System.out.println("Employee Name is :"+name);
        System.out.println("Employee Department is :"+department);
        System.out.println("Company is :"+companyname);
    }
}

public class CompanyUse {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        CompanyDetail cd = new CompanyDetail(int Id,String name,String department);
        cd.getdata();
        cd.printdata();
    }
}
```

i am getting error in a main block when i create a object..eclips keep teeling me that constructor CompanyDetail() is undefined....and without constructor it gives me a null value in my output..please help me ..i ve just started learning java...thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default constructor (with empty parameter list) is created automatically by the compiler only when you don't create any other constructor. In your case you have `CompanyDetail(int ID,String Name,String Dept)` so it wasn't automatically generated. You could write default constructor yourself:

```
CompanyDetail() {}
```

Also I have some tips:

- this code isn't compiling, please fix all the errors - java compiler is quite good at saying what's wrong with code (:
- never, ever use empty catch block,
- try to follow naming conventions popular in Java.